# Eigenvalue of the product of two matrices with the same eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If two $n\times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ both have the same eigenvalue $\lambda$ does this mean their product $AB$ has eigenvalue $\lambda$

Comment: Did you try any example so far, say, with $2\times 2$-matrices?

Comment: I think I found a counterexample. (See Below)

Comment: I just posted it now

Comment: If $A$ has eigenvalue $\lambda$ then $A^2$ has eigenvalue $\lambda^2$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: take $A=B$ with a diagonal matrix, say, in $M_2(K)$ or even in $M_1(K)$ having an eigenvalue $\lambda>1$.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a counterexample.
Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2\\ 1 &0\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix}1& 1\\ 1&1\end{bmatrix}$. The only eigenvalue these matrices share is $2$. Their product $AB$ is $\begin{bmatrix}3 & 3\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$ which has eigenvalues $0$ and $4$.

Comment: It is easier with, say, $A=B=(2)$ as $1\times 1$-matrix. Both have eigenvalue $\lambda=2$, but $AB=(4)$ has eigenvalue $4$ (the eigenvalues of diagonal matrices are on the diagonal).